# Configuration objects which are subject for frequent copies?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

Using C#, I currently ran into the problem of how to store configuration objects which are subject to copy&change very frequently. Maybe configuration is not the best word, but contextual data is.

Think of I have a basic configuration template, which will be passed through a workflow. Inside this workflow, every step should take the preceeding configuration, maybe copy and modify it, and pass it to the next step. Important is, that a subsequent step does not change the configuration from its predecessor.

Normally I'd say: well, just use a flat class with simple members. But, of course, a configuration could also contain more complex members like a `List<T>`. Copying objects in C# is not fun and copying them frequently sounds like a nightmare for the GC. But not using the type-system and abusing a `Dictionary<string, object>` does not sound that good either.

Another requirement is a human readable data storage on disk. I thought of using JSON or something alike.

What is the best way to store data like this?

*Note: I know there are several questions like this. Please remember I'm not asking for "fast serialization" oder "how to deep-clone objects" at best. I'm asking what is the best format to store data like this.*

Comment: `if (OP.Text.Contains("What is the best")) OP.Close(CloseReason.OpinionBased)`

Comment: I won't agree to this. There are a _lot_ of best practices out there. Maybe there is one for this, and I just don't know it?

Comment: Just serialize your data to disk (for example as json) before continue to next step. Next step then can just modify this data futher - you have a copy on disk already.

Comment: This is so damn easy that I wonder why I didn't come to that solution myself. Thank you!